# How to Install Oracel RDBMS 11G?

Tags: software-installation, oracle, database

Currently I am learning  **Relational Database Management system**. In college everyone is using with Windows, but I want to use on Linux.

How do I install RDBMS 11G on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to install either VMWare or VirtualBox, and load Oracles' very own brand of Linux into a virtual machine.  They even have pre-made images that you can download  [Oracle VM images](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html)

Comment: thats too large 23 GB... http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/portal/downloads/owcp-vm-2251396.html @Charles Green..

Comment: I'm sorry - I pointed at the wrong link.  I'll edit my answer in a moment, bet the correct link is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

Comment: sorry charles  little stupid question...which should i should i download  ? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/odi-demo-2032565.html

Comment: For me, the best solution was to download Oracle Linux and Oracle 12g seperetely, install the Linux is VirtualBox, and then install the Oracle in VirtualBox.  There was some learning involved:  Oracle Linux is based on RedHat, and some commands in the terminal are a little different.